# library not found for -lFirebase (expo eas build failed)

Tags: firebase, react-native, expo, eas

I am building a react native expo app and when I am trying to build the app using 'eas build --platform ios' command and my build is failing in the Run fastlane step. Here is the error :

ld: library not found for -lFirebase
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

I am using firebase as the db and backend of my app. I have absolutely no idea what this error is and how to fix it. Can anyone please help me with this ?

I tried

1. pod install
2. pod update
3. opne {projectName.xcworkspace} with xcode then Build Phases->Link Binary With Libraries-> add FirebaseCore.a

but nothing worked